# Unity 5.5. splash screen doesn't show up on iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I'm working at a new version of my Game implemented with Unity. With Unity 5.4 it correctly shows the Unity Splash Screen... now that I've moved to Unity 5.5 the splash screen just doesn't show up and after a couple of seconds the game starts with the initial Scene. I see they have released the new splash screen tool... should I have to change anything to have the Unity Logo again?!

(I cannot release without the logo since I'm using the Personal edition).

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug for now. It seems that the fix won't be available until Unity 5.5.1p1 according to [this post](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/5-5-splash-not-appearing-in-build.443769/).